# Form.Show() is "Not Responding..."

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, children

I have a little trivial problem in my application. I have a dialog (d1) that inherits from Form. And in Main, if I call

```
d1.ShowDialog
```

,it works fine. But calling

```
d1.Show()
```

opens a bad form with pale labels and textboxes, and when I try to drag that window form it says "Not Responding."

What's going on? I think I need "Show" and not "ShowDialog," because the user should be dealing with several simultaneous forms.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is that the message loop is not being properly hooked up to the form.  Not my area of expertise but my first thought would be to make sure the parent form was properly set.